# How does a python method automatically receive 'self' as the first argument?

Tags: python, oop, methods, self

Consider this example of a strategy pattern in Python (adapted from the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/963965/how-is-this-strategy-pattern-written-in-python-the-sample-in-wikipedia)). In this case the alternate strategy is a function.

```
class StrategyExample(object):
    def __init__(self, strategy=None) :
        if strategy:
             self.execute = strategy

    def execute(*args):
        # I know that the first argument for a method
        # must be 'self'. This is just for the sake of
        # demonstration 
        print locals()

#alternate strategy is a function
def alt_strategy(*args):
    print locals()
```

Here are the results for the default strategy.

```
>>> s0 = StrategyExample()
>>> print s0
<__main__.StrategyExample object at 0x100460d90>
>>> s0.execute()
{'args': (<__main__.StrategyExample object at 0x100460d90>,)}
```

In the above example `s0.execute` is a method (not a plain vanilla function) and hence the first argument in `args`, as expected, is `self`.

Here are the results for the alternate strategy.

```
>>> s1 = StrategyExample(alt_strategy)
>>> s1.execute()
{'args': ()}
```

In this case `s1.execute` is a plain vanilla function and as expected, does not receive `self`. Hence `args` is empty. Wait a minute! How did this happen?

Both the method and the function were called in the same fashion. How does a method automatically get `self` as the first argument? And when a method is replaced by a plain vanilla function how does it *not* get the `self` as the first argument?

The only difference that I was able to find was when I examined the attributes of default strategy and alternate strategy.

```
>>> print dir(s0.execute)
['__cmp__', '__func__', '__self__', ...]
>>> print dir(s1.execute)
# does not have __self__ attribute
```

Does the presence of `__self__` attribute on `s0.execute` (the method), but lack of it on `s1.execute` (the function) somehow account for this difference in behavior? How does this all work internally?

Comment: You can think of `instance.method(arg)` as a shorthand for `InstanceClass.method(instance, arg)`. Python tries to keep things as simple and obvious as possible, and I find this a "transparent" way of accessing the instance that called the function

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can read the full explanation [here](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#types) in the python reference, under "User defined methods". A shorter and easier explanation can be found in the python tutorial's description of [method objects](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#method-objects):

> If you still don’t understand how methods work, a look at the implementation can perhaps clarify matters. When an instance attribute is referenced that isn’t a data attribute, its class is searched. If the name denotes a valid class attribute that is a function object, a method object is created by packing (pointers to) the instance object and the function object just found together in an abstract object: this is the method object. When the method object is called with an argument list, a new argument list is constructed from the instance object and the argument list, and the function object is called with this new argument list.

Basically, what happens in your example is this:

- a function assigned to a class (as happens when you declare a method inside the class body) is... a method.

  - When you access that method through the class, eg. `StrategyExample.execute` you get an "unbound method": it doesn't "know" to which instance it "belongs", so if you want to use that on an instance, you would need to provide the instance as the first argument yourself, eg. `StrategyExample.execute(s0)`
  - When you access the method through the instance, eg. `self.execute` or `s0.execute`, you get a "bound method": it "knows" which object it "belongs" to, and will get called with the instance as the first argument.
- a function that you assign to an instance attribute directly however, as in `self.execute = strategy` or even `s0.execute = strategy` is... just a plain function (contrary to a method, it doesn't pass via the class)

To get your example to work the same in both cases:

- either you turn the function into a "real" method: you can do this with `types.MethodType`:

  ```
  self.execute = types.MethodType(strategy, self, StrategyExample)
  ```

  (you more or less tell the class that when `execute` is asked for this particular instance, it should turn `strategy` into a bound method)
- or - if your strategy doesn't really need access to the instance - you go the other way around and turn the original `execute` method into a static method (making it a normal function again: it won't get called with the instance as the first argument, so `s0.execute()` will do exactly the same as `StrategyExample.execute()`):

  ```
  @staticmethod
  def execute(*args):
      print locals()
  ```

Comment: Very clear answer and that too straight from the Python tutorial!!! Shows that I should revisit the tutorial again to absorb the deeper language details that I just skimmed over a long time back. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 8):

You need to assign an unbound method (i.e. with a `self` parameter) to the class or a bound method to the object.

Via the [descriptor mechanism](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#descriptors), you can make your own bound methods, it's also why it works when you assign the (unbound) function to a class:

```
my_instance = MyClass()    
MyClass.my_method = my_method
```

When calling `my_instance.my_method()`, the lookup will not find an entry on `my_instance`, which is why it will at a later point end up doing this: `MyClass.my_method.__get__(my_instance, MyClass)` - this is the descriptor protocol. This will return a new method that is bound to my_instance, which you then execute using the `()` operator after the property.

This will share method among all instances of MyClass, no matter when they were created. However, they could have "hidden" the method before you assigned that property.

If you only want specific objects to have that method, just create a bound method manually:

```
my_instance.my_method = my_method.__get__(my_instance, MyClass)
```

For more detail about descriptors (a guide), see [here](http://users.rcn.com/python/download/Descriptor.htm).

Comment: It's funny how the only answer that actually shows you you can make a bound method and tries to explain it didn't get a single upvote...

Comment: The descriptor access is a method of creating methods that I didn't know about. I've always done it using the instance method constructor.

Comment: @kindall: Do you mean like shown in the article you linked to? Instead of obtaining it via `type()`, you can import it: `from types import MethodType`

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much how I've always done it. Good point about `MethodType`, I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: @pahnt0m Your answer clarified a lot about how a method is resolved by looking it up in the Class. Thanks!

Comment: @Praveen: You're welcome. Please note that I have added a link to a guide about descriptors which has much more information than I provided here. It also tells you about the `__set__` equivalent.

Answer (score 6):

The method is a wrapper for the function, and calls the function with the instance as the first argument. Yes, it contains a `__self__` attribute (also `im_self` in Python prior to 3.x) that keeps track of which instance it is attached to. However, adding that attribute to a plain function won't make it a method; you need to add the wrapper. [Here is how](http://irrepupavel.com/documents/python/instancemethod/) (although you may want to use `MethodType` from the `types` module to get the constructor, rather than using `type(some_obj.some_method)`.

The function wrapped, by the way, is accessible through the `__func__` (or `im_func`) attribute of the method.

Comment: Very helpful analogy: "The method is a wrapper for the function ...". And thanks for the link!

Answer (score 1):

When you do `self.execute = strategy` you set the attribute to a plain method:

```
>>> s = StrategyExample()
>>> s.execute
<bound method StrategyExample.execute of <__main__.StrategyExample object at 0x1dbbb50>>
>>> s2 = StrategyExample(alt_strategy)
>>> s2.execute
<function alt_strategy at 0x1dc1848>
```

A bound method is a callable object that calls a function passing an instance as the first argument in addition to passing through all arguments it was called with.

See: [Python: Bind an Unbound Method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015307/python-bind-an-unbound-method)

Comment: The term is that you have an unbound method. If you /bind/ the method (which you can do), it'll again implicitly pass the instance as the first argument.

Comment: Thanks for the link about binding an unbound method!