# Python - Inline get one member of tuple from delegate

Tags: python, tuples, inline-functions

From [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8864153/how-to-declare-a-dictionary-with-inline-function) functions cannot be defined inline in a dictionary object.

However, I just have this simple case,

```
def getExtension(fileName):
    return os.path.splitext(fileName)[1]

funcDict = { 
    'EXT': getExtension,  # maybe os.path.splitext[1]?
    }

print(funcDict['EXT']('myFile.txt'))
```

Is there someway to specify that I only want one element of the tuple returned by `os.path.splitext` so I can get out of defining `getExtension`?

Comment: Can't you use lambdas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
funcDict = {
    'EXT': (lambda x: os.path.splitext(x)[1])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I this it's sometimes better to use keyword arguments to instantiate a new dict, as the keyword arguments seem more readable.

```
funcDict = dict(EXT=(lambda x: os.path.splitext(x)[1]))
```

which will return:

```
{'EXT': <function <lambda> at 0x00000000021281E0>}
```