# Python Strategy Pattern: using class wrapper not function + simple_vs_easy_logic

Tags: python, strategy-pattern

I am trying to build a Strategy Pattern using S.Lott's [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/964345/886368).
Problem is function returns None.
Am using Hickey's Simple vs Easy {what, how, who}-logic.
-[WHAT] I/O

```
class base_fnc(object):
    def fncExc(self,data1,data2):
        return
```

-[HOW] DATA <> queue[where,when] (direct injection)

```
class stump( base_fnc ):
    def fncExc(self, d1, aContext):
       return d1

class MAB(base_fnc ):
     def fncExc(self, d, aContext ):
        return d+10
```

-[WHO] API

```
class context( object ):
    def __init__(self, alt_how_class ):
        self.how = alt_how_class

    def exc(self, d ):
        return self.how.fncExc(d, self)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    c1 = context(MAB())
    ss=c1.exc(10) 
    print ss
```

ss prints None

Comment: Downvoting because this is unlikely to be useful for others. No offense.

Answer (score 2):

You're not returning in `exc`.  You need to do `return self.how.fncExc(d, self)`.