# Static method-only class and subclasses in Python - is there a better design pattern?

Tags: python, oop, abc

I am pricing financial instruments, and each financial instrument object requires a day counter as a property. There are 4 kinds of day counters which have different implementations for each of their two methods, `year_fraction` and `day_count`. This day counter property on financial instruments is used in other classes when pricing, to know how to discount curves appropriately, etc.  However, all of the day count methods are static, and doing nothing more than applying some formula.

So despite everything I've read online telling me to not use static methods and just have module-level functions instead, I couldn't see a way to nicely pass around the correct DayCounter without implementing something like this

```
class DayCounter:
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta

    @abc.abstractstaticmethod
    def year_fraction(start_date, end_date):
        raise NotImplementedError("DayCounter subclass must define a year_fraction method to be valid.")

    @abc.abstractstaticmethod
    def day_count(start_date, end_date):
        raise NotImplementedError("DayCounter subclass must define a day_count method to be valid.")


class Actual360(DayCounter):

    @staticmethod
    def day_count(start_date, end_date):
        # some unique formula

    @staticmethod
    def year_fraction(start_date, end_date):
        # some unique formula


class Actual365(DayCounter):

    @staticmethod
    def day_count(start_date, end_date):
        # some unique formula

    @staticmethod
    def year_fraction(start_date, end_date):
        # some unique formula


class Thirty360(DayCounter):

    @staticmethod
    def day_count(start_date, end_date):
        # some unique formula

    @staticmethod
    def year_fraction(start_date, end_date):
        # some unique formula

class ActualActual(DayCounter):

    @staticmethod
    def day_count(start_date, end_date):
        # some unique formula

    @staticmethod
    def year_fraction(start_date, end_date):
        # some unique formula
```

So that in a pricing engine for some particular instrument that is passed an instrument as a parameter, I can use the instrument's day counter property as needed.

Am I missing something more idiomatic / stylistically acceptable in Python or does this seem like appropriate use for static method-only classes?

---

***Example***:

I have a class FxPricingEngine, which has an `__init__` method passed an FxInstrument and subsequent `underlying_instrument` property. Then in order to use the `Value` method of my pricing engine I need to discount a curve with a particular day counter. I have a `YieldCurve` class with a `discount` method to which I pass `self.underlying_instrument.day_counter.year_fraction` such that I can apply the correct formula. Really all that the classes are serving to do is provide some logical organization for the unique implementations.

Comment: Those classes are just namespaces. The inheritance that you've implemented is simply artificial and not needed at all. It would be cleaner to turn them into modules with functions IMHO.

Comment: @freakish Maybe this is too localized and I should just give up on this question but if you look at the example at the bottom of my question, can you see my issue with having modules with functions? I would need to somehow pass around a parameter associated with an instrument representing what module to use?

Comment: Module is an object as well. If you can pass around classes then you can pass around modules.

Comment: Take a look at the discussion on the strategy pattern in Python: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/963965/how-to-write-strategy-pattern-in-python-differently-than-example-in-wikipedia

Comment: @HavelTheGreat Oh, you mean that you want to retrieve module dynamically by say a string or int? Then you create a dictionary with keys that map to modules.

Comment: @freakish That's what I'm going to end up doing, I think, sort of goes hand in hand with the answer I accepted. Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it is, object orientation does not make any sense in your scenario: there is no data associated with an instance of your types, so any two objects of some type (e.g. `Thirty360`) are going to be equal (i.e. you only have singletons).

It looks like you want to be able to parametrise client code on behaviour - the data which your methods operate on is not given in a constructor but rather via the arguments of the methods. In that case, plain free functions may be a much more straight forward solution.

For instance, given some imaginary client code which operates on your counters like:

```
def f(counter):
  counter.day_count(a, b)
  # ...
  counter.year_fraction(x, y)
```

...you could just as well imagine passing two functions as arguments right away instead of an object, e.g. have

```
def f(day_count, year_fraction):
    day_count(a, b)
    # ...
    year_fraction(x, y)
```

On the caller side, you would pass plain functions, e.g.

```
f(thirty360_day_count, thirty360_year_fraction)
```

If you like, you could also have different names for the functions, or you could define them in separate modules to get the namespacing. You could also easily pass special functions like way (for instance if you only need the day_count to be correct but the year_fraction could be a noop).

Answer (score -1):

Well to be frank it doesn't make much sense in defining static methods this way. The only purpose static methods are serving in your case is providing a namespace to your function names i.e. you can call your method like `Actual365.day_count` making it more clear that day_count belongs to `Actual365` functionality.

But you can accomplish the same think by defining a module named `actual365`.

```
import actual365
actual365.day_count()
```

As far as Object Orientation is concerned, your code is not offering any advantage that OOP design offers. You have just wrapped your functions in a class.

Now I noticed all your methods are using start_date and end_date, how about using them as instance variables.

```
class Actual365(object):

    def __init__(self, start_date, end_date):
        self.start_date, self.end_date = start_date, end_date

    def day_count(self):
        # your unique formula

    ...
```

Besides `AbstractClasses` don't make much sense in Duck-Typed languages like Python. As long as some object is providing a behavior it doesn't need to inherit from some abstract class.

If that doesn't work for you, using just functions might be better approach.

Comment: Perhaps I didn't explain fully - say I have a class FxPricingEngine, which has an `__init__` method passed an FxInstrument. Then in order to use the `Value` method of my pricing engine I need to discount a curve with a particular day counter. Hence I use `some_fx_instrument.day_counter.year_fraction` to apply the correct formula.

Comment: Also, `start_date` and `end_date` change on many calls - making them instance variables would not work.

Comment: So then defining them as static methods don't make much sense either

Comment: In OOP paradigm object should represent some real/virtual entity. Your class is not representing anything if it doesn't have properties of its own

Comment: It is nothing more than namespace for your functions

Comment: I understand that in general, but it's representing a type of day counter. Do you see my issue regarding how I would pass a daycounter from an instrument around as I need to without the classes?

Comment: if you want to persist state of start_date and end_date, why not create multiple instances with dates as instance variables as I mentioned

Comment: That is simply not feasible. A day counter is used in a Discount method for a yield curve, for instance. Which is called hundreds and hundreds of times with different dates, after being passed a day counter as a parameter independent of those dates.

Answer (score -1):

## No

Not that I know of. In my opinion your design pattern is ok. Especially if there is the possibility of your code growing to more than 2 functions per class and if the functions inside a class are connected.

If any combination of function is possible, use the **function passing** approach.
The **modules** approach and your approach are quite similar. The advantage or disadvantage (it depends) of modules is that your code get split up into many files. Your approach allows you to use `isinstance`, but you probably won't need that.

### Passing functions directly

If you had only one function, you could just pass this function directly instead of using a class. But as soon as you have **2 or more functions** with different implementations, classes seem fine to me. Just add a docstring to explain the usage. I assume that the two function implementation in one class are somewhat connected.

### Using modules

You could use modules instead of classes (e.g. a module Actual365DayCounter and a module Actual360DayCounter) and use something like `if something: import Actual360DayCounter as daycounter` and `else: import Actual365ayCounter as daycounter`.

Or you could import all modules and put them in a dictionary (thanks to the comment by @freakish) like `MODULES = { 'Actual360': Actual360, ... }` and simply use `MODULES[my_var]`.

But I doubt this would be a better design pattern, as you would split up your source coude in many tiny modules.

### Another  option:

One way would be to use only one class:

```
class DayCounter:
    def __init__(self, daysOfTheYear = 360):
        self.days_of_the_year = daysOfTheYear
```

And make the functions using `self.days_of_the_year`. But this only works if `days_of_the_year` is actually a parameter of the function. If you would have to use a lot of `if ... elif .. elif ...` in your function implementation, this approach would be worse

Comment: You don't do `if something: import ...`. This is ridiculous. You create a dictionary `MODULES = { 'Actual360': Actual360, ... }` and then you do simply `MODULES[my_var]`. You would do exactly the same with classes otherwise (by using `getattr` for example) it would be unsafe.