# Python bind method to another instance

Tags: python, class, methods, instance

I need to merge two methods from different instances of different classes to a single instance of a class.

For example I define two classes:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "a"

    def print_name(self):
        print(self.name)


class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "b"

    def print_name(self):
        print(self.name)
```

and then I will try to make another object c and its `print_name` method must return the results of `a.print_name()` and `b.print_name()` so I tried the following :

```
a = A()
b = B()
c = A()

c.name = "c"
c.print_name_1 = a.print_name
c.print_name_2 = b.print_name
def final_print(self):
    self.print_name_1()
    self.print_name_2()
c.print_name = MethodType(final_print, c)
c.print_name()
```

Expected output:

```
c
c
```

but I get :

```
a
b
```

I tried to use types.MethodType as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10374527/dynamically-assigning-function-implementation-in-python) but it creates some kind of a method which takes two arguments : the first one will be the 'a' instance and the second one will be the 'c' instance.

Any help to do that properly?

Comment: Overriding methods on a per-instance basis defeats the purpose of having a class, which is to provide a *uniform* interface for all instances of the class.

Comment: My goal is to create a new object by merging two others, I don't know how to do that with another way

Comment: Should `c` be an instance of `A`, or should it really be an instance of a *new* class? Also, do `A` and `B` really need to be separate classes, or can `a` and `b` be instances of the same class, just with different values for the `name` attribute?

Comment: So a,b,c inherit from the same class, let's call it `Parent`, but they are different classes with different methods

Answer (score 1):

I managed to succeed with this, thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61155832/12827800). I am using the `__func__` attribute of a method. So here is the code :

```
c.name = "c"
c.print_name_1 = MethodType(lambda instance: copy.deepcopy(a.print_name).__func__(instance), c)
c.print_name_2 = MethodType(lambda instance: copy.deepcopy(b.print_name).__func__(instance), c)
def final_print(self):
    self.print_name_1()
    self.print_name_2()
c.print_name = MethodType(final_print, c)
c.print_name()
```

Comment: While this works, it's probably not the correct solution to whatever end goal you are hoping to achieve.

Comment: To describe more precisely my intend, it is to create a parent class Parent, and two types of parent called A and B which have their own implementation of the function print_name. 
Here I want to merge A and B to create a new class or instance dynamically (in the code above it is c) that has a function with the same name (i.e. print_name), and this function must execute first the method print_name defined in A, and then the method print_name defined in B. But the self argument in these functions refers to the instance c. So do you have any idea how to merge this methods into one dynamically ?

Comment: That's still crazy. Why do you want to do that? Having methods with different names in A and B would let you easily have a wrapper which dispatches the method with a different name, so in A you would have `def method(): return(a_method)` and in B `def method: return(b_method)`. Now in C you can easily inherit from both A and B and `def method: a_method(); return b_method()` or whatever.

Comment: Tangentially, maybe see also mixins.

Comment: I need the methods to have the same name because my program works with sort of callbacks. At some point in the program I call instance_of_parent.print_name(). So that’s why I need to have a method print_name in c

Comment: Yes yes, so define it like A: `def print_name(): return a_specific_print_name()` and B: `def print_name(): return b_specific_print_name()` and then in C `def print_name(): a_specific_print_name(); b_specific_print_name()`